# Firebase nested data using "reference" : true instead of array

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

On the firebase [structure data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/structure-data#fanout) section, it shows how to structure data with a many-many user-group situation. But, why they have used "referece":true on both the side instead of using a simple array od ids.

Like, it can be used like both the ways:

1. A user having array of groups

   ```
   "groups" : [ "groupId1", "groupId2", ... ]
   ```
2. A user having

   ```
   "groups": {
       "groupId1" : true, 
       "groupId2" : true,
       ..
   }
   ```

They have done it a second way. What is the reason for that?

Something was told at the Google I/O 2016 for that in some video. But, I'm unable to recall.

Example from structure your data:

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase recommends against using arrays in its database for most cases. Instead of repeating the reasons here, I'll refer you to this classic [blog post on arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Let's look at one simple reason you can easily see from your example. Since Firebase arrays in JavaScript are just associative objects with sequential, integer keys, your first sample is stored as:

```
"groups" : { 
  0: "groupId1", 
  1: "groupId2"
]
```

To detect whether this user is in `groupId2`, you have to scan all the values in the array. When there's only two values, that may not be too bad. But it quickly gets slower as you have more values. You also won't be able to query or secure this data, since neither Firebase Queries nor its security rules support a contains() operator.

Now look at the alternative data structure:

```
"groups": {
    "groupId1" : true, 
    "groupId2" : true
}
```

In this structure you can see whether the user is in `groupId2` by checking precisely one location: `/groups/groupId2`. It that key exists, the user is a member of `groupId2`. The actual value doesn't really matter in this case, we just use `true` as a marker value (since Firebase will delete a path if there's no value).

This will also work better with queries and security rules, because you now "just" needs an exists() operator.

For some great insights into this type of modeling, I highly recommend that article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Got the point! Actually I saw someone explaining `/groups/groupId2 != null` in I/O 2016, But I totally forgot the usage and unable to find that particular video. Thanks for explaining awesomely! I came across that NoSQL data modeling article last week. In my reading list!